# Non-trivial solutions of $x(x-1) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ 10^k)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I need to show that there are exactly two non-trivial solutions of $$x(x-1) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ 10^k)$$for any $k$.

The only thing I've figured out is that one of the numbers has to be divisible by $2^k$ and another one has to be divisible by $5^k$ (and it could not be even). I'd be happy if someone gives me any help or advice!

Comment: What do you mean by finding them? If you want an explicit formula, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Actually, I need only to show that there are exactly two non-trivial solutions.

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but you could set $x(x-1)=n10^k$.

Comment: What counts as "trivial" solutions? $x \equiv 0,1$ mod $10^k$?

Comment: Yes, these ones

Comment: Since two answers have already been posted saying that $x(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{10^k}$ implies either $x\equiv 0 \pmod{10^k}$ or $x-1\equiv 0 \pmod{10^k}$, and were subsequently deleted after a simple counterexample ($x=6,k=1$) was pointed out, I thought I'd make note of those events in a comment. I hope this saves anyone else the wasted effort of posting such an answer.

Comment: @DavidK Lmao, thank you for being a genius and saving lives before they are lost.

Answer (score 5):

You're right about your observation, let's look at the cases:

1. If $2^k\lvert x$, then $5^k\lvert x-1$. So, 
   $$x\equiv 0\pmod{2^k}\text{ and } x\equiv 1\pmod{5^k}$$
   By Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a unique $x$, between $0$ and $10^k-1$ satisfying these equations.
2. Similarly, if $2^k\lvert x-1$, then $5^k\lvert x$. So, 
   $$x\equiv 1\pmod{2^k}\text{ and } x\equiv 0\pmod{5^k}$$
   By Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a unique $x$, between $0$ and $10^k-1$ satisfying these equations, too. And clearly two cases give different solutions.

Comment: >.< And this is what happens when you don't learn in any serious kind of way.

Comment: Oh yes, how could I forgot about CRT

Comment: @SimpleArt I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Oh, its just that I don't spend time actually trying to learn math.  I just pick up bits and pieces and put them together (hopefully well), which is why I can solve some integrals with complex analysis techniques but lack a basic understanding of real analysis.